# What is this error Phantom nodes that are not targeted by a link mapping representing containment reference present in model

Tags: eclipse-gmf

When i am generating gmfgen model from gmfmap this error validation is shown." Phantom nodes that are not targeted by a link mapping representing containment reference present in model. "

What is the solution of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it meant that I forgot to specify a 'containment feature', which is a property of a node in the .gmfmap file.

I realize this is too late for you, but I arrived here through Google and so might other people.